# Servicestack - Passing information between sessions

Tags: session, authentication, servicestack

I have implemented a custom AuthenticateAttribute, AuthUserSession and CredentialsAuthProvider. In the Execute method of my AuthenticateAttribute I do:

```
public override void Execute(IRequest request, IResponse response, object requestDto)
    {
        var session = request.GetSession() as IMyCustomAuthUserSession;

        // Copy certain request headers into a dictionary on my session object
    }
```

I need to store certain special headers that are sent to me for later use. This works correctly when authentication is not enabled. When authentication IS enabled and the user has to log in, the TryAuthenticate method of my CredentialsAuthProvider class fires:

```
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        var session = authService.GetSession() as IMyCustomAuthUserSession;
    }
```

The sessions in these to methods are not the same since the session I get in the TryAuthenticate method - which fires after the AuthenticateAttribute.Execute method - does not contain the headers I stored there.

The special headers are only sent in the very first call to the web server so I need to get them into the new session of the TryAuthenticate method.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Passing Session data between logins is going to be difficult as Sessions are invalidated between Authentication attempts. You can choose to retain the same Session Cookies between logins by configuring the `AuthFeature` plugin with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    GenerateNewSessionCookiesOnAuthentication = false
});
```

Which will retain the same users `ss-id/ss-pid` cookies on Login.

#### Use SessionBag for persisting Data between Auth Sessinos

For persisting data outside of an Authenticated User Session you can [use a SessionBag](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-dynamic--untyped-sessions-in-servicestack), e.g:

```
//Save
base.SessionBag["cart"] = new Cart { ... };

//Retrieve
var cart = base.SessionBag.Get<Cart>("cart");
```

#### Persisting User Data under a Custom Cookie

An alternative solution is to persist data under a Custom Cookie, that way it wont get invalidated by ServiceStack during Authentication.

Where you can register a Global Request Filter to ensure each client/browser has a custom Cookie Id, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req,res,dto) => {
    var uniqueId = SessionExtensions.CreateRandomSessionId();
    var httpRes = res as IHttpResponse;             
    httpRes.Cookies.AddPermanentCookie("my-id", uniqueId);
    req.Items["my-id"] = uniqueId; //if also needed for this request
});
```

Then on subsequent requests you can persist data under your unique Cookie Id, e.g:

```
var uniqueId = req.GetSessionParam("my-id");
var cacheKey = $"urn:Cart:{uniqueId}";
var cache = req.GetCacheClient();
cache.Set(cacheKey, new Cart { ... });
```

Then later retrieve it with:

```
var uniqueId = req.GetSessionParam("my-id");
var cacheKey = $"urn:Cart:{uniqueId}";
var cache = req.GetCacheClient();
var cart cache.Get<Cart>(cacheKey);
```